# Importing own JavaScript modules into converted TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert an existing JavaScript codebase to TypeScript one file at a time. Hitting a problem with the imports.

Converting:

```
// JavaScript
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
```

to:

```
// TypeScript
import AWS = require("aws-sdk");
```

works as the AWS SDK is installed in `node_modules`. When I try to `import` one of my own modules, converting:

```
// This works, but is it "correct"? Path here is relative to compiled .js file
const C = require('../utils/constants');
```

to:

```
import C = require('../utils/constants');
```

it fails with `Cannot find module '../utils/constants'.ts(2307)`.

For context, here are the paths of the concerned files (all paths relative to project root):

1. Module file I am trying to use: `utils/constants.js`
2. Original `.js` file: `utils/sesUtil.js`
3. Equivalent `.ts` file: `src/utils/sesUtil.ts` (this is the one we're discussing here)
4. Compiled `.js` file: `dist/sesUtil.js`

Leads me to some questions:

1. What is the correct way to import my own (CommonJS) JavaScript modules?
2. Should the path be relative to where the `.ts` file exists (`src/utils/ses.ts`) or relative to where the compiled `.js` file will go (`dist/ses.js`)?

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: As already posted in answer - do not use `require`. Use `import * as C from ''` or `import C from ''`.

Also, make sure to set `rootDir` and `outDir` like "mirroring". Your `outDir` structure will be mirroring your `rootDir` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regard to problems with path. Make sure to set, at least, `rootDir` and `outDir` properties - [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

> --rootDir - specifies the root directory of input files. Only use to control the output directory structure with --outDir.
>
> --outDir - redirect output structure to the directory.

E.g. you have a source file in `src/animal/Dog.ts`. It will appear in `dist/animal/Dog.js` with the following setup:

```
"rootDir": "src",
"outDir": "dist"
```

`include` field is also must to be set as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details). These are the usual UNIX glob patterns for the files to include for compilation. You also can use `files`, but `files` is for including the exact file, it is not a glob pattern. So community prefers to use `include`.

Regard to `require` in TypeScript code. Preferably to forget about `require` at all (except some edge cases). If you want to import evertything from the module, use:

```
import * as MyModule from './MyModule';
import MyModule from './MyModule';
```

Comment: Thanks. What do I do with the `include` in `tsconfig.json`? Leave it as it is or remove it completely?

Comment: Leave it as is. It is a proper glob pattern for "include everything from sources". I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement for:

```js
const C = require('../utils/constants');
```

is:

```js
import * as C from '../utils/constants';
```

Regarding import paths - relative to the file you are importing into, or relative to project's root directory, I decide based on context.

1. Are those 2 files part of the same implementation and likely to move together (for example to new folder)? Then use `../` paths, relative to each other.
2. Is file I am importing part of separate unit/implementation? Then use path from root directory (eg `src/...`).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've added a list explaining the locations of the various files. Maybe that will help explain better.